# Which monitor connector: DVI or VGA?

Tags: dvi

I just got my new workstation and plugged it into the ordinary VGA 15-pin connector. The monitor does not pick up the signal.

Do I have to use a DVI port? I can see several on this machine.

The workstation powers up great. I do not want to go out and buy a DVI cable before I know if that would help.

Should not the monitor -always- pick up the signal from the 15 pin port?

[image: Inputs 1]

Comment: You also have a HDMI connection there too. That should work with tv (with a HDMI input) as a quick check. Most new monitors have multiple input sockets, HDMI, DVI, SVGA and DisplayPort.

Comment: Will get HDMI and DVI cables tomorrow. :)

Comment: @PdC Please be aware that some places sell HDMI cables at an artificially high price. It could be worth comparing what you intend to buy with Amazon's and Monoprice's own-brand cables.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, duly noted, thanks alot for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have other video ports. Some machines have on board VGA that is disabled when a graphics card is plugged in.

(Edit: I see you have video card HDMI and Display ports. HDMI cables are fairly easy to come by and chances are you already have a TV with HDMI, try it first)

Comment: The images above are photos of the only connectors I have on the workstation. 1 VGA and three DVI (?)

Comment: Your other 2 DVI ports (+ HDMI and Display port) appears to come from a graphics card. So I think it is because you have graphics card that your on board video is disabled. You should invest in DVI or HDMI as you get better video quality.

Comment: It appears you have a dual-monitor video card (GPU) installed.  If you are using only one monitor, ensure you are plugging it into the correct DVI port.

Comment: Sounds about right, it's a gaming rig.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a graphics card installed there. I think that your PC is not outputting to VGA (15 pin) because you have a graphics card, you should plug your monitor into your graphics card. Side note: DVI is better quality than VGA and your graphics card has a HDMI port on it. If your monitor has HDMI on it then you should use that instead, you can pick up HDMI cables pretty cheaply.

Comment: Do you mean the connector next to the VGA connector (next to the VGA which is highlighted in yellow?)

Comment: you should read up on connectors.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Visual_Interface

Comment: @PdC the middle connector in that [http://imgur.com/gCBFEig] photo

Comment: You're right Daniel. But it could be then that the graphics card is using a DVI connector and I have to connect to that one?

Comment: @PdC you should really use the graphics card that comes installed... It will always be better than the motherboards intergrated graphics. And you welcome =]

Comment: @Firix, so it does not have to be an error that the VGA port is not working? It might simply not be attached to the graphics card?

Comment: Well, the VGA in this [link]http://imgur.com/XD8kvGr image are connected to the motherboards integrated graphics chip. If you have a graphics card connected then the integrated graphics chip will probably not output. So its probably not an error. The two pictures are of two different components.

Comment: @Firix, Ok, when a separate graphics card is "active", the integrated one could be configured not to work at all if connected with a VGA port (now presupposing the integrated is using VGA?)

Comment: Yes, but it wouldn't make a difference what you connected to the integrated chip, it wont output.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following.
 - is the graphics card properly seated?  (turn the computer off when checking)
 - are you connecting the monitor to the GPU ?
 - check the monitor is connected to the default output port on the graphics card. (or, get two monitors and connect them both).

I suspect you have everything working correctly, but haven't plugged the monitor into the correct output port.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. First I have to get a DVI cable. Haven't had a stationary computer in 7 years.

Comment: And laptops haven't had VGA in years, mostly they have one of DVI/DisplayPort/HDMI

Comment: My laptop has a VGA port and I bought it exactly a year ago..

Comment: When I buy cheap second tier laptop I too get old hardware features.

Answer (score 0):

Some motherboards disable her own graphics output when a Graphics Card is installed, like in your case. It is highly recommended to use the output from the graphics card to receive full graphics potential from your workstation. Check if your monitor has other connectors available like the ones on your graphics card, DVI-D (left), HDMI (center) or DisplayPort (right).

If you don't have those available on your monitor you have to consider purchasing an adapter for your monitor, or switching to a newer monitor instead.

Comment: This confirms it, I'll get HDMI and DVI cables tomorrow. Thanks!